# how can sum N char with variable in tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

how can sum N char with variable in tsql?

this sql query return correct result

```
select * from PersonsInfoTbl where Name LIKE  N'علی%';
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndoJP.jpg)

this sql query return incorrect result

```
declare @Name nvarchar(50)
set @Name = 'علی';
select * from PersonsInfoTbl where Name LIKE  N''+@Name+'%';
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUA7v.jpg)

My database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must prefix any nvarchar string literal with an N.  If you don't do that, SQL Server will assume that it's not an nvarchar.

For example:

```
declare @Name1 nvarchar(50), @Name2 nvarchar(50)

set @Name1 = N'علی';
set @Name2 = 'علی';

select @Name1 "Name1", @Name2 "Name2"
```

Will return this:

```
 Name1     Name2    
 --------  -------- 
 علی       ???
```

Try this:

```
declare @Name nvarchar(50)
set @Name = N'علی';
select * from PersonsInfoTbl where Name LIKE @Name + N'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem you set the variable @Name without the N'', this is nessecary for sql to know you set it as nvarchar

```
declare @Name nvarchar(50)
set @Name = N'علی';
select * from @t where Name LIKE  N''+@Name+'%';
```

this will return the rows

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable to store the SQL command as a string. Also you need to use the unicode N on your variables and commands so that text is also stored as unicode.

```
declare @Name nvarchar(50)
declare @sqlcmd nvarchar(max)
set @Name = N'علی';
set @sqlcmd = N'select * from PersonsInfoTbl where Name LIKE  '''+@Name+'%'''
EXECUTE(@sqlcmd)
```

Edit: I suppose the dynamic part is not necessary in this specific case, but you will find this useful in writing queries in the future.